# PowerBI report cannot recognize If statement when string are compared

Tags: powerbi, report, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm trying to replicate the example presented in this youtube tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z9ttZAZkEhs

However, even if I use the same DAX code the controls do not recognize the values properly.

```
Selected = calculate (DimProduct[uniqueCustomer],  treatas( Values(Products[Name]), DimProduct[EnglishProductName] ) )
```

I tried different ways to recognize the values coming from the slicer, but they simply do not work.

```
CheckColumn = if (trim(DimProduct[EnglishProductName]) = trim(DimProduct[SelectedNumber2]),true,false)
```

I have attached the example file that I'm using.

[image]

https://github.com/gabrielacosta/TestPowerBiSlicer/blob/main/testslicer.pbix

Does anyone know what could be the issue.

Comment: I think your model is slightly different from the one in the video. You need the Sales Table to perform the same calculations.

Comment: Hi Angelo, To be honest. What I need is the proper management of the slicer controls and how to integrate the selection with the interaction on the fields. So, my example is showing only the basic interaction with the slicer that is not working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your calculation should look like the formula below but it doesn't make much sense doing that calculation.

```
Selected = 
CALCULATE (
    [uniqueCustomer],
    TREATAS ( VALUES ( Products[Name] ), DimProduct[EnglishProductName] ),
    VALUES ( DimProduct[EnglishProductName] )
)
```

For this specific scenario just using `SELECTEDVALUE` is better

```
Selected2 =
    VAR SelectedProduct =
        SELECTEDVALUE ( Products[Name] )
    VAR CountCalc =
        CALCULATE (
            [uniqueCustomer],
            FILTER ( DimProduct, [EnglishProductName] = SelectedProduct )
        )
    RETURN
        CountCalc
```

Comment: Hi Angelo, thanks for the help. Btw, the first Selected throws an error of circular dependency. I check the second one and I'm not sure how it is related to my issue. What I want to know is when the selected slicer match one specific product, that flag 1 is marked. So, my initial solution was to compare using the IF condition. But that simply does not work. I used the calculation on the youtube example and it does not work either.